# Is this a bug in C++? (Book <<C++ primer>> might be wrong?)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

```
//Wrong Code
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    istream_iterator<string> in_iter(cin),eof;
    ostream_iterator<string> out_iter(cout," ");
    while(in_iter!=eof)
        *out_iter++ = *in_iter++;
}
```

Input:(Run the code above in ***interactive mode*** through "visual c++"、"cpp.sh"、"onlinegdb" and whatever tool you like...)

```
aa bb cc 6 dd ee
```

Output:

```
aa bb cc 6 dd
```

**Actually the correct code should be:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    istream_iterator<string> in_iter(cin),eof;
    ostream_iterator<string> out_iter(cout," ");
    while(in_iter!=eof){
        *out_iter = *in_iter;
         out_iter++;
         in_iter++;
    }
}
```

Input:

```
aa bb cc 6 dd ee
```

Output:

```
aa bb cc 6 dd ee
```

**Description:** Very easy code. Just for printing some characters and output will be the same. However, in the book of "C++ Primer", as the picture shown below, it gives us a wrong code. Is it a bug of C++ or just the mistake of "C++ Primer"?
[Picture of "C++ Primer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJeKO.png)

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7f1ab708e5fd618).

Comment: They are logically equivalent, so there should not be any difference. How are you entering the input?

Comment: I run these two code through "Visual Studio 2019" and "cpp.sh", an online C++ compiler. However, for the wrong code , whatever I input, the output will miss one value...

Comment: Seems to be something about the eof, try it on cpp.sh not in interactive mode but in text mode, there it works.

Comment: reproduce in onlinegdb

Answer (score 1):

Let's take apart this command and see what's happening:

```
*out_iter++ = *in_iter++;
```

It can be also written in the following way, according to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

```
// read next value, but return unmodified iterator (with the previous value)
// the first value is read when the iterator is constructed!
auto x = in_iter++; 

// get value that was previously read
const auto res = *x; 

// print this value
*out_iter++ = res;
```

So basically this prints a value only *after* reading the next one.
For an input of `"a b c"` the following happens:

1. constructor `istream_iterator<string> in_iter(cin)` reads `"a"`
2. `auto x = in_iter++;` reads `"b"`, but returns an iterator containing `"a"`
3. `const auto res = *x;` results in `"a"`, which then is printed.
4. `auto x = in_iter++;` reads `"c"`, but returns an iterator containing `"b"`
5. `const auto res = *x;` results in `"b"`, which then is printed.
6. `auto x = in_iter++;` tries to read something, but the streambuffer is empty, so it waits for further input.

So far only `"a b"` was printed and `"c"` is "stuck" in `in_iter`.

If the stream would contain an `[eof]` (e.g. if you terminate the stream somehow), step 6 would be different and step 7 (and 8) would happen:

6. `auto x = in_iter++;` reads `[eof]`, becomes the eof-iterator and returns an iterator containing `"c"`
7. `const auto res = *x;` results in `"c"`, which then is printed.
8. loop terminates

So this code is not wrong, it just does not do what one would intuitively expect.

---

Your code on the other hand does the following:

```
// extract first value that was read by the constructor and "prepare" to print
*out_iter = *in_iter; 

// read next value
out_iter++;

// print value
in_iter++;
```

This works as expected, because it does prints the old value *before* it reads a new one.